# How can I show this fact about analytic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I have the following problem:

> Let $f,g$ be analytic functions when $|z|<2$. Let us define $D=max\{|f(z)|+|g(z)|: |z|\leq 1\}$. Let us suppose that $M=|f(w)|+|g(w)|$ for some $w$ with $|w|\leq 1$. Then I need to show that $|w|=1$.

So my Idea is the following:

> Let us remark that $\Omega=\{|z|<2|\}$ is open and path connected, thus also connected. Furthermore we know that $f,g:\Omega \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ are analytic. In addition we remark that $D=max\{|f(z)|:|z|\leq 1\}+max\{|g(z)|:|z|\leq 1\}$. Thus $$|f(w)|=sup_{|z|\leq 1}|f(z)|,~~~|g(w)|=sup_{|z|\leq 1}|g(z)|$$Now using the maximal priciple gives us that $f,g$ are constant, so the maximum is attaint everywhere in $\Omega$.
>
> Furthermore we have the equalities that $\alpha f=|f|$ and $\beta g=|g|$ for some $\alpha, \beta$ modulus one numbers. This gives us $$|\alpha f+\beta g|\leq |f|+|g|$$ Since $f,g$ attains the maximum inside $\Omega$ also $|f|+|g|$ does, therefore we have that $$\alpha f(w)+\beta g(w)=|f(w)|+|g(w)|$$ which is a maximum for |f|+|g|.

Is this correct so far? But now I don't see how to finish so that I can conclude that $|w|=1$.

Comment: This has been done here before ($|f|+|g|$ attain maximum inside a domain, then $f,g$ constant so the maximum is attained everywhere and the idea is that if $w$ is inside the domain and $\alpha f(w)=|f(w)|, \beta g(w)= |g(w)|$ then $\alpha f +\beta g$ which is analytic has a maximum inside the domain, so is constant and from there it is not hard to get $f,g$ constant

Comment: Hmm sorry I don't get it exaclty to say that $\alpha f(w)=|f(w)|$?

Comment: could you maybe explain this a bit more

Comment: For any complex number $z$ there is a unique modulus one number $\alpha$ st $|z|=\alpha z$ (unless $z=0$ when any modulus one works); then $|\alpha f+ \beta g|\le |f|+|g|$ by the triangle inequality which combined to the fact that at $w$ we have $\alpha f(w)+\beta g(w)=|f(w)|+|g(w)|$ maximum for $|f|+|g|$ gives that $w$ is a maximum modulus of $\alpha f+\beta g$ so that is constant and equal to $|f|+|g|$ which is also constant everywhere so we have equality in the triangle inequality as above etc

Comment: And why do we know that since $M$ is inside a domain then $f,g$ are constant, does this come from the maximal principle?

Comment: The maximum principle implies that $\alpha f +\beta g$ is constant but then the triangle inequality implies that also $|f|+|g|$ is constant and we have equality in the triangle inequality which leads to $f,g$ constant

Comment: So I try it now but would it be possible to upload here my new solution so that you could take a look?

Comment: I uploaded a possible solution, could you maybe take a look? It would be very nice because I somehow struggle a bit.